# How to remove characters from a specific place in a string(not by index) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code:

```
def myprogram():
import string
import random
import getpass

inputpasswd = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
passwd = ("I<3StackOverflow")
if passwd == inputpasswd:
    qwerty = input("Type something: ")
    def add_str(lst):
        _letters = ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","q","w","e","r","t","z","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","y","x","c","v","b","n","m","!","#","$","%","&","/","(",")","=","?","*","+","_","-",";"," ")
        return [''.join(random.sample(set(_letters), 1)) + letter + ''.join(random.sample(set(_letters), 1))for letter in lst]

    print(''.join(add_str(qwerty)))
    input("")
else:
    print("Wrong password")
    input("")
```

My question is: How can I make an opposite program, so it accepts the bunch of junk letters and converts it to text that makes sense?

Example:
If I type something like "aaaaaaa" in this program it will convert it to something like "mapma&)at7ar8a2ga-ka*"

In this new program I want to type "mapma&)at7ar8a2ga-ka*" and get output "aaaaaaa".

Comment: I don't see how `"aaaaaaa"` would be "text that makes sense". Also how does the title relate to your question?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) is some useful bedtime theory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
s="1a23a45a6"
print(s[1::3]) # aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Do so: `initial_str = random_str[1:-1:3]`, where random_str is string with junk